# how to get previously selected tab after dismissing modal IOS

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an application using UITabBarController. There are 5 tabs (tab1, tab2, cameraTab, tab3, tab4). When user taps on middle tab , the modal view will appear hiding the TabBar (in my case camera - UIImagePickerController). If user then taps on cancel button on that modal view, how do I make it to return to previously selected tab. For example: if i am on tab2 and I tap on the camera tab, modal view appears and then I tap on cancel, how do i return back to tab2 automatically. The same goes for all other tabs, if I'm on tab3 it should return to tab 3 and so on. Right now it remains on camera tab without modal view - just blank view with background image.

I'd really appreciate if you can help me with some examples. I've been searching in various ways - there must be a way that UITabBarController keeps a record of previously selected tab.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you should create a custom view where the middle camera tab would not be a tab at all, it would actually just be a button that presents the modal view and then that view would have a button to dismiss it. I would do a little research in http://idevrecipes.com/ to see if there is anything there. If not, maybe github. The tab bar itself is looking for views to push, not present.

I am sorry I couldn't give you more of an answer, but I wanted to give you something for waiting so long.

Comment: thanks AlienDev at least for responding. I'll check on the link you sent me and if I don't find anything I'll start thinking how to implement your approach of a button. I wonder how Instagram does it.